# Ruby finding frequency of string sequence

Tags: ruby, string

I am trying to figure out how to find the most repeated sequence of words within a string.

I have this string for example:

```
s = "this is the time, no it's not. This is the time! no it's not, This is the time? it is the time"
```

I want to find out which 3 words in sequence occurs the most. In the case above it would be `'is the time'=>4`

I have a messy way of figuring out which 3 words split by white space are repeated the most.

```
s.strip.downcase.split(/[^\w]+/).group_by(&:to_s).map{ |w|
 {w[0]=>w[1].count}}.sort {|x,y| y.values.first <=> x.values.first }.first(3).reduce({}, :merge)
```

which will return `{"the"=>4, "time"=>4, "is"=>4}`

This seems a lot more intense because it would need to find the word before and after it and then store that particular combination and increment a count if the combination appears, then do the same thing with the next word till the end of the string. It's dealing with a smaller subset within the string each time, so the calculation should not get more complex if the string had to become 1 million words long.

Is there any easy ruby convention to achieve this.

Comment: I don't have time to write a real answer so a comment with a few pointers will have to do. The search terms you want to use are n-grams, trigrams and bag-of-words. It's a pretty well researched area in natural language processing, spam filters and the like use them (among other tools). Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks @JackBracken I will do some more reading :)